# Can \documentclass{minimal} create documents with nonstandard page sizes?

Tags: document-classes, paper-size, minimal

I need to create a document for a square piece of paper. I've been trying to use `\documentclass{minimal}`, but it doesn't work.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\special{papersize=14in,14in}
\setlength{\paperwidth}{14in}
\setlength{\paperheight}{14in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{12in}
\setlength{\textheight}{12in}

\topskip0pt
\setlength{\headheight}{0pt}
\setlength{\headsep}{0pt}
\setlength{\topmargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}

\begin{document}
\ldots
\end{document}
```

But the PDF file I get is by no means square. What is wrong with my code?

Comment: Do not use `minimal`, IMHO it's more a coding example than a real class. What's the problem with using `article`?

Comment: I didn't know how to change paper size - I'm quite a beginner, my LaTeX guides don't cover this, and this is what I'd found on the web. You must be right that article is indeed OK.

Comment: @Tymon do a `texdoc geometry` and go through the documentation of `geometry` package to find all these details.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `geometry` package to set paper size.

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage[paperwidth=14in,paperheight=14in,margin=2in,showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-13]
\end{document}
```

[image]

For more details, execute`texdoc geometry` from the command prompt and go through the documentation of geometry package.

Like Martin said in the comment, it is better to use some other class since they support extended features.

Comment: @Tymon, If you find this answer useful, you may consider accepting it by checking the green tick mark above and also consider upvoting.

Comment: Sure, I've just accepted it, but I can't upvote - too little reputation.